# How well received were the Hobbits in Valinor?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

Were there Elves who were angry that Hobbits were there? Or were they curious to see another species? Or were they Welcomed to them as guests? Or simply bewildered at the sight of "outsiders" in Valinor?

Is there any part of the Middle Earth books that give any information as to what happened when the Hobbits landed on Valinor?

Comment: **Elves and hobbits are the same species.** Notably, per Tolkien and per basic mammalian biology, elves and men are the same species, and their differences are spiritual, not biological. (Elves are effectively humans before expulsion from Eden in the Judeo-Islamic sense.) Also: hobbits and men are the same species: hobbits are simply a group of tribes of relatively diminutive stature. Therefore, elves and hobbits are the same species.

Comment: @Lexible, clearly species identification is transitive.

Comment: @MichaelFoster Heh.

Answer (score 9):

There are no writings about the lives of the Hobbits in the Undying Lands. The only detail Tolkien wrote is that they eventually died there.

The fact that they arrived accompanied by Galadriel and Elrond, both highly-born Noldor, and Gandalf, an (incarnated) angelic spirit, probably wouldn't have hurt their social standing. Having been so integral in defeating Sauron, who is probably not looked upon too favourably in the Undying Lands, probably wouldn't have hurt either.

But all of this is speculation; we have absolutely no idea.

Comment: Can we assume that they were suprised the Valar let them come to their land?

Comment: @Fingolfin Probably no more surprised than they would have been about Eärendil

Comment: eh Earendil was half Elven so they probably didnt care as much

Comment: @Fingolfin Sure, if you ignore the point that it was supposed to be impossible for anyone, including the Elves, to go to Valinor at the time and the only reason Earendil succeeded was that he had a Silmaril.

Comment: Did they make Valinor, my understanding is Valinor is the continent beyond Tol Erreseä which is where the ships went before going on to Valinor.

Comment: @AncalagonTheBlack Not known. In Letter 297 Tolkien says that Galadriel finished her Lament with a prayer that Frodo be allowed to go to Eressea, but that's not evidence that he did or didn't stay there

Answer (score 2):

The hobbits found great hospitality in Elrond's house in Rivendell. I don't think their reception in Tol Eressea would have been different.

I'd be more worried about Gimli the Dwarf (who Legolas took with him there as well). :o)

Comment: Worried about Gimli? You might want to re-read his interactions with Galadriel. The fact that he's holding the three silmarils (locks of hair) would be miraculous to them. There's a reason why he was permitted to go there.